# Why does the product of a function containing zeros and infinities produce a continuous function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, infinite-product, singularity

Why does the product of $\sin ^2(\pi  x)$ and $ \sum _{i=1}^4 \cot ^2 (\frac{\pi  x}{i} )$ with the singularities of the later produce a continuous function?

The function

$\sin ^2(\pi  x)\,\,\,\,\,(1)$

produces zero's for some values and the function

$ \sum _{i=1}^4 \cot ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{i}\right)\,\,\,\,\,(2)$

produces singularities for some values of $\cot ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{i}\right)$.

How can for example $\sin ^2(\pi  x) \sum _{i=1}^4 \cot ^2 (\frac{\pi  x}{i} )$ give approximately at $x=2$ $y=5$, $x=3$ $y=10$, $x=4$ $y=20$ when plotted?

How is this worked out in each case?

Should not an infinity times a zero equal zero?

At $x=4$ for example $\sum _{i=1}^4 \cot ^2 (\frac{\pi  x}{i} )$ give infinity + infinity + infinity + $\frac{1}{3}$, then times $\sin ^2(\pi 4)$ which somehow produces 20.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number so those are still singularities, but you can create a function which is continuous by defining values for those singularities. Similarly to how $x\times \frac1x$ has a singularity at $x=0$ but you can extend it to be $1$ for $x=0$ to get a continuous function.

Comment: @kingW3 how does one define values for singularities or is just arbitary. in the case of x=4 above  would this suggest 3.(59/9) +1/3 =20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that you have a function $f(x)$ which has singularities and another function $g(x)$ which has zeros at those singularities, in such a way that $g(x)f(x)$ has what are called [removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). These are points where, strictly speaking, the function is undefined, yet there is a consistent way to modify the definition of the function at the singularities such that it becomes continuous.

Infinity times zero is an indeterminate form, for the same reason that infinity divided by infinity is indeterminate. This means that it can take any value whatsoever, depending on how infinity and zero are approached.

For example, both $x$ and $x^2$ tend to $0$ as $x\to 0$, and likewise both $1/x$ and $1/x^2$ tend to $\infty$ as $x\to 0$, however by multiplying together these functions we can obtain three different behaviors:
$$
x\cdot 1/x
$$
tends to $1$ as $x\to 0$,
$$
x^2\cdot 1/x
$$
tends to $0$ as $x\to 0$,
$$
x\cdot 1/x^2
$$
tends to $\infty$ as $x\to 0$.

Thus, whenever we encounter infinity times zero expressions, in order to continue we need to compare how quickly the infinity is approached and how quickly the zero is approached. It's a tug of war...

Now you asked how the value is determined, in the case of a removable singularity. It's actually the same as asking how to calculate a limit, in general - since any limit can appear in such a question. In your case, the functions are nice enough that we can calculate the limits directly: for each $i=1,\ldots,4$

$$\sin^2(\pi x)\cdot \cot^2(\pi x/i)=\cos^2(\pi x/i)\cdot \left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\sin (\pi x/i)}\right)^2$$

The only places where there can be a singularity is when the denominator $\sin(\pi x/i)$ equals $0$, which occurs whenever $x=in$ for some integer $n$. Thus to answer your question, it will suffice to find
$$
\lim_{x\to in}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\sin (\pi x/i)}.
$$
Since both the numerator and denominator tend to $0$, we may apply [this rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) to obtain that
$$
\lim_{x\to in}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\sin (\pi x/i)}=
\lim_{x\to in}\frac{\pi\cos(\pi x)}{\tfrac{\pi}{i}\cos (\pi x/i)}=\frac{\pi (-1)^{in}}{\tfrac{\pi}{i}(-1)^n}=i(-1)^{(i-1)n},
$$
where we have taken the derivative in the first step, calculated the limit in the second step by plugging $x=in$ into the cosines, and then did some algebraic simplification in the last step.

Thus,
$$
\lim_{x\to in}\sin^2(\pi x)\cot^2(\pi x/i)=\cos^2(\pi n)\cdot \bigl(i(-1)^{(i-1)m}\bigr)^2=i^2,
$$
whereas when $m$ is an integer that is not a multiple of $i$, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to m}\sin^2(\pi x)\cot^2(\pi x/i)=\sin^2(\pi m)\cot^2(\pi m/i)=0
$$
since there is no singularity in the second factor (and the first factor is zero).

As a result, your function takes the following values:
$$
x=2\colon y=1^2+2^2,\qquad x=3\colon y=1^2+3^2,\qquad x=4\colon y=1^2+2^2+4^2,
$$
notice in each case that it is the sum of the squares of the divisors.

Comment: if I want to calculate say x=4 then would that be $\sum _ {i = 1}^4 i (-1)^{4 (i - 1)}$ but this equals 10 not 30 and $\cos^2 (\pi 4)\left (\sum _ {i = 1}^4 i (-1)^{4 (i - 1)} \right)$ the same since the $cos$ is one at the integers?

Comment: Split the sum into the four terms separately. For a given term $i$, my formula applies only when $x$ is of the form $in$. Otherwise, you don't need any limit calculation - there is no cancellation of singularities. When $x=4$, this means you apply the limit calculation only when $i=1$ (so $n=4$), when $i=2$ (so $n=2$), or when $i=4$ (so $n=1$). For $i=3$ you just plug in. Then add those four results...

Comment: okay so I get $(-1)^{(1-1) 4}+(-1)^{(2-1) 2}+(-1)^{(4-1) 1}+0=1+1+(-1)+0=1$ which does not give 21 so I think I've still not understood.

Comment: That's the limit of the expression inside the square. You still have to square it and multiply by $\cos^2(\pi x/i)$. Anyway from this discussion it is clear I need to add some more lines to my answer - I thought it was clearer.

Comment: @onepound I have updated my answer to make the final step explicit, including an explanation of where the $21$ comes from.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand it finally.

Answer (score 1):

Considering
$$y=\sin ^2(\pi  x) \sum _{i=1}^4 \cot ^2 \left(\frac{\pi  x}{i}\right)$$ expand using multiple angle formula in terms of $\frac {\pi x}{12}$ and let $t=\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{12}\right)$. You should arrive at
$$y=30-1824 t+47440 t^2-666944 t^3+5609216 t^4-29830144 t^5+104058880 t^6-243122176
   t^7+382271488 t^8-398721024 t^9+264241152 t^{10}-100663296 t^{11}+16777216
   t^{12}$$ which cannot be factored and does not show any real root.

If $x$ is an integer, this produces integer results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
 0 & 30 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 5 \\
 3 & 10 \\
 4 & 21 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 6 & 14 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 8 & 21 \\
 9 & 10 \\
 10 & 5 \\
 11 & 1 \\
 12 & 30 \\
 13 & 1 \\
 14 & 5 \\
 15 & 10 \\
 16 & 21 \\
 17 & 1 \\
 18 & 14 \\
 19 & 1 \\
 20 & 21 \\
 21 & 10 \\
 22 & 5 \\
 23 & 1 \\
 24 & 30
\end{array}
\right)$$

You could have observed the same phenomena wih
$$y_n=\sin ^2(\pi  x) \sum _{i=1}^n \cot ^2 \left(\frac{\pi  x}{i}\right)$$ using
 $t=\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{\text{lcm}(1,2,\cdots,n)}\right)$

For example
$$y_1=1-t$$
$$y_2=5-12 t+8 t^2$$
$$y_3=14-240 t+1708 t^2-5952 t^3+10624 t^4-9216 t^{5}+3072 t^{6}$$
$$y_n=P_{\text{lcm}(1,2,\cdots,n)}(t)$$

Comment: how does one expand using multiple angle formula in terms of $πx/12$?